# How to tell if piano has "clicky hammers" problem?

Tags: piano, repair

I bought a used piano and learned that some in the brand (Baldwin) are prone to having some problem with "clicky hammers". How can I tell if that is the case? I cannot hear anything wrong myself, but am not experienced with pianos either.

Comment: If you can't hear it, it's not a problem.

Comment: This video demonstrates it here around the 40 second mark, but I also can't hear it in the video: https://youtu.be/EH96fYhjtdo?t=44

Answer (score 7):

#### You would hear it

Hammer click is a very distinctive sound. When heard, it leaves no doubt that there's a problem.

There are a variety of videos on YouTube, for example, demonstrating hammer clicking noises. Hearing to two or three of those will make clear what to listen for.

Here's one example, chosen at random. The click is quite distinct.

#### Have a technician check out your piano

For reassurance, the best thing to do is have a technician check things out and make recommendations for helpful fixes and improvements. You can choose whether or not to invest in those recommendation, but it will give you confirmation regarding hammer clicking.

It sounds like this is a recent purchase, so it should be tuned (at minimum) after being in its new home for a couple of months. That would be a good opportunity for a technician to look it over more generally.

The Piano Technicians Guild website can help [you find a local technician](https://portal.ptg.org/4dcgi/directory/rpt/person.html).

#### Baldwin-specific problems?

For this, a concrete reference is needed. I'm not familiar with Baldwin-specific problems and could not find anything in searching.